# identity oprators and memory location in python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, operators, identity

```
x1, y1, x2, y2, d1, d2 = 5, 5, 'Hello', 'Hello',  {'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1, 'b':2}
x1_is_y1= x1 is y1
x2_is_y2= x2 is y2
d1_is_d2= d1 is d2
print(x1_is_y1," ",x2_is_y2," ",d1_is_d2)
```

the output is ofcourse 'true true false' ! I am new to python and want to know that even though dictionaries are mutable if compared to strings and ints but yet here i am declaring the dictionaries using two different variables! then why do they point to the same memory location like in c++? isnt it fine , even though inefficient, to save the same thing in two different variables which must point to two different memory locations?

Comment: What do you mean by "they point to the same memory location"? They don't - `d1 is d2` returns `False` because you defined two separate dictionaries, just with the same value. Immutable data types like ints and strings can share memory, because they will never be modified in place, and so never change the value of other identifiers pointing to the same address.

Comment: i assume the same! maybe i need to recheck the authenticity of the source !